# What are the requirements to develop for Nokia Lumia?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-phone-7, nokia, smartphone

In the development of application in Nokia Lumia, what is the platform that can be used?
since Nokia was partnered by Microsoft, is it okay to develop an application in Visual Studio? using Smart Device Application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use Visual Studio 2010, since the current version of the Lumia is a Windows Phone 7.5 Device.

More information here:

[Smart Device Development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa69he4t.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can program it using Visual Studio and Silverlight.

[A video tutorial is available here](http://www.silverlight.net/archives/tutorials/building-a-windows-phone-7-application)

Comment: is it okay to used vb.net than c#?

Answer (score 0):

You can develop Windows Phone applications using VS2010 and the Windows Phone SDK (you can get the SDK at http://create.msdn.com/en-US/). Windows Phone actually uses a specific version of Silverlight.